# entityQuery array instead of orConditionGroup()

Tags: 8, entities, database

I'd written a query based on the "simplified" version [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3AorConditionGroup/8.2.x). And my code looked like this.

```
$results = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'mytype')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('field_first.target_id', $anArrayOfNids)
  ->condition('field_seciond.target_id', array($anotherNid))
  ->execute();
```

The code was working, I know it was. But now I'm getting an "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens" SQL error.

I tried replacing it with just array(540) and got the proper result. Then I gave it array(546) and got the different, expected response, but as soon as I put [540,560] or array(540,560), I get that error, instead of what i used to get, which was the combined results.

Comment: What's changed since it used to work? (broad overview will do...core upgrades? config changes? etc)

Comment: No module upgrades. Only one or two other parts of the module, and minor, that should have affected it at all, and I did everything to remove to test it; once I tried the hardcoded array and it didn't work, I was stumped.

Comment: Yeah, can't think of a reason that wouldn't work (but I do seem to remember seeing something similar reported somewhere recently, I'll try to dig it up)

Comment: Out of interest what happens if you explicitly set the operator, e.g. `->condition('field_first.target_id', [123, 456], 'IN');`?

Comment: That fixed it. Wow. I DID not have that before, and the example off of drupal.org , doesn't have it. I'll leave a comment. I'm wondering what happened. I'm 99% sure I didn't run any OS updates on my VM until AFTER I started having that issue--because that's why I noted that there was a mysql update--but, that's the only thing I'm aware of that even comes close to explaining it.

Comment: Thought it might, I can't find the related question/issue right now but I vaguely remember that being the thing that solved it. If memory serves no one involved in the conversation knew why it had suddenly happened either. Smells like a bug I think, especially as it works without  using `IN` when you only have one of those array conditions in the query. I think it's unlikely this had anything to do with OS updates, that conversion all happens in Drupal code

Comment: Well, I left a comment, so hopefully it'll avoid at least one more of these type of scenarios: https://xkcd.com/979/ Thanks!

Comment: Heh, that's my favourite xkcd :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how it was working before, but the solution seems to be to place the explicit 'IN' in the query as such:

```
$results = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'mytype')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('field_first.target_id', $anArrayOfNids, 'IN')
  ->condition('field_seciond.target_id', array($anotherNid))
  ->execute();
```

Or, if I was to just convert this to the more complicated, yet more robust method:

```
$results = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$group = $query->orConditionGroup();
foreach($anArrayOfNids as $nid) {
  $group->condition(field_first.target_id, array($nid));
}
$query->condition('type', 'mytype')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('field_seciond.target_id', array($anotherNid))
  ->condition($group)
  ->execute();
```

Comment: The second option isn't more robust, justs more complex. Explicitly passing IN is required since before 8.0.0 but I think there's a bug that it works with an array that just has a single entry without IN